# Kafka connect to Tera data

Tags: apache-kafka, teradata

Please any one can know how to connect to Tera data with Kafka?

I reviewed the many sites but I didn't get proper solution.

Comment: Did you check the manuals? There's an [Access Module for Kafka](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_Lake_VMware/Teradata-Tools-and-Utilities-Access-Module-Reference-17.20/Teradata-Access-Module-for-Kafka) for Teradata's TPT.

Comment: Can be done using Teradata's JDBC driver and Kafka's JDBC connector, possibly using some third-party orchestration tool. Teradata's client utilities also include a Kafka "access module" for more of a batch processing approach.